# How to find Software by developer on a Mac (System software from developer was blocked from loading)

Tags: macos, mac, security

In my Security & Privacy settings, I have a request for software to run by nothing has dodgy as a: Kim Jensen?!

A Google-search points in the direction of the crappy software that is impossible to remove: Jabra Suite. But how do I know exactly?

I recently migrated from another Mac to this one, so there has be a bunch of re-authentication.

And how do I link that request to the App by the developer?

And also. I can only see an 'Allow'-button. How do I decline or remove that request?

[image: System software from developer Kim Jensen]

Comment: You decline the request by not allowing the unsigned application from loading.  [It seems straight forward to remove the software you mentioned though](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jabra/comments/ez2n1v/jabra_direct_uninstallation_instructions_for/?utm_source=BD&utm_medium=Search&utm_name=Bing&utm_content=PSR1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @ramhound is correct in pointing you to a post that shows how to remove that particular software it doesn't answer the other part of the question that allows you to see applications installed and sort them by developer:

1. Go to Apple Menu > About this Mac
2. Click on System Report
3. The System Information app opens.
4. Scroll down on the left to Software and open up the disclosure triangle (if necessary) and click on Applications
5. It will take a minute for the list to populate with all software installed on your Mac
6. Click the "Obtained From" column heading to sort by developer and find the developer in the list you are looking for.

It **should** show you the same name that shows in Security & Privacy, if not you may have to guess or eliminate apps from known developers. In your case it may be listed under "Jabra."

Comment: Awesome! That works. So in order to 'decline the permission request', I should just uninstall / delete the application(s) by that developer. Right?

Comment: Notice the button in Security & Privacy. There is no deny, only allow. So it is already denied. If you launch it again you will get the opportunity to deny it *again* though...

Comment: Thank you!  Still useful.